# Css overlay element not invisible

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

See:
http://schhh.dk/frivilligraadet/

The box with videos at the bottom are, in ie8, displayed as:
[image: Videos]

I actually tried to make a jsfiddle, but here there is no problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/q5T8Y/7/

```
.view-youtube-videoer .views-field-field-video .ytb-play {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 128px;
  background: transparent url('http://schhh.dk/frivilligraadet/sites/all/themes/frivilligraadet/images/play.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you need to set "width" and "display: block" for span.ytb-video
In your case width should be 230px

http://screencast.com/t/U2QPWvszGN

Answer (score 0):

Is an issue with transparency an IE I'm afraid. The configurations and hints in this link can help you out: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it in dev tools, for some reason the filter rule and width rule are combining into one. Even though they are separated by a semicolon (see screenshot), maybe the combination is "broken." and this is why the element has no width.

From the CSS I can't tell right away why IE8 would be interpreting them this way -- they're not even consecutive in the file! Maybe just try reordering them to see if that makes a difference. Or change it to

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
```

which is the better version for IE8 anyway.

[image: Screenshot]